# How could I replace '$uid=*any digit*' using preg_replace function?

Tags: php

Basically, I need to replace the text inside a php file in-order to slightly change a mysqli query.

I'm using this function:

```
file_put_contents($file,preg_replace('/^($uid=)[\d]/', '$uid=' . $uid, file_get_contents($file)));
```

to replace

```
$uid=*any digit*
```

in the php file represented by $file.

It works perfectly when I match basic patterns, but

```
'/^($uid=)[\d]/'
```

doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protect `$`, as `\$` the digit is alone ? may be `\d+`

simple sample:

```
<?php
$string="\$uid=123testest space was here";
echo preg_replace('/^\$uid=(\d+)/','$1 uid lalala',$string);
```

output:

```
123 uid lalalatestest space was here
```